# What might be the reason for this kind of difference in output?

Tags: c, arrays

I made the follwoing piece of code for a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    //code
    int t; int k;
    /*t= length of string and k=character upto which should be counted*/

    int *count = (int*)malloc(26*sizeof(int));
    //Dynamic Array of count.

    scanf("%d %d\n",&t,&k);
    char c;
    for(int i =0;i<t;i++){
       scanf("%c",&c);
       count[c-'A']++;
    }
    int min = 999999;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        if(min>count[i]) min=count[i]; //Calculating minimum
    }
    if(min==0) printf("0");
    else printf("%d",min*k);
    return 0;
}
```

Though some of the compilers were giving correct output of the program. The online judge wasn't giving correct output to it. I changed the code a bit and now it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    //code
    int t; int k;

    scanf("%d %d\n",&t,&k);
    int count[26];
    char str[100020];

    for(int i=0;i<t;i++) 
        scanf("%c",str+i);
    for(int i =0;i<t;i++){
       count[str[i]-'A']++;
    }

    //Rest from here is unchanged.

    int min = 999999;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        if(min>count[i]) min=count[i]; //Finding the minimum of count.
    }

    if(min==0) printf("0");
    else printf("%d",min*k);

    return 0;
}
```

Though both of them is supposed to do the same thing why is the output different by the online judge?

INPUT :
9 3

ACAABCCAB

Correct Output : 6. Wrong output by my code was 9.

P.S Do comment if problem statement is required.

Comment: You made at least two changes: You changed `count` from dynamically allocated with `malloc` to automatically allocated with `int count[26]`, and you changed the character processing from one-at-a-time with `char c` to buffered with `char str[10020]`. (a) Why don’t you make one change at a time and test how the judge responds to each change separately? (b) Does the judge force `malloc` to return failure (`NULL`)?

Comment: Before `count[str[i]-'A']++;`, recommend `if (str[i] < 'A' || str[i] > 'Z') { printf("oops %d\n", str[i]); exit(-1); }` or the like.  `count[str[i]-'A']` is dangerous without protection.

Comment: @chux He hasn't linked to the problem statement, but they usually specify preconditions on the inputs that you're allowed to rely on.

Comment: @Barmar Had code not included the `'\n'` in `scanf("%d %d\n",&t,&k);` (`'\n'` is usually advised against there), the 1st `count[str[i]-'A']++;` would certainly be UB.  OP's code is teetering on the edge of UB.

Comment: OT: the special case for `min==0` isn't needed, since `min*k` is 0 when `min` is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions are wrong, because you never initialize the values in `count` to `0`.

In the first version, where you use dynamic allocation, you can use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`, as it automatically zeroes the memory:

```
int *count = calloc(26, sizeof(*count));
```

In the second version, where you just declare an array, you can provide an initialization list:

```
int count[26] = {0};
```

There's no need for the `str` array that you put in your second version. Since you're processing the input one character at a time, a single `char` variable is fine.

There's also no need for the `if` statement at the end. If `min == 0`, then `k * min` is also `0`, so printing `min * k` will print `0`.

Comment: While typing I failed to notice your almost identical answer!

Comment: I wonder why no compiler seems to be able to catch & warn about such common mistakes as this -- for the second version at least, it has all the info it needs.

Comment: I don't know. But a tool like `valgrind` will catch it.

Comment: @mosvy : Possibly some compilers will if optimisation is enabled, because optimisation requires the kind of deep-flow analysis that can spot such errors.  It is often a good idea to switch on the optimiser at max even if you don't finally deploy fully optimised code.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions increment `count` elements without `count` being initialised.  The fact that one works and the other does not is more by luck than judgement.  It is a shame that the "judge" does not apply static analysis to the code and just reject it for poor quality rather then simply accepting anything that happens to produce an apparently correct result.

In the second:

```
int count[26] = {0} ;
```

In the first:

```
int* count = calloc(26, sizeof(int) ) ;
```

but dynamic memory allocation serves no purpose here, and failing to release it is and additional quality issue.

The use of `str` in the second also serves no purpose. A better solution will be a combination of both - the initialised array, and the use of a single char to receive input.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few actual or potential problems, depending on what the online judge does and what compiler (or compiler settings) it uses.

Both cases have undefined behaviour, since elements of `count` are not initialised.   Accessing their values (e.g. which is necessary to increment them) gives undefined behaviour.    Among other things, that means the behaviour can vary for creating the arrays in different ways (e.g. `malloc()` versus an automatic array) in both samples.

The first sample does not check that `malloc()` succeeds.   If `malloc()` fails (returns `NULL`) subsequent code that uses `count` has undefined behaviour.

`scanf()` can encounter errors.  This will be indicated by its return value.  For example, it can return `EOF` to indicate end of stream, or a value indicating the number of values it successfully read.   For example, if `scanf("%d %d\n",&t,&k)` return `1`, only the value of `t` will be changed, and `k` may not.   If `k` is unchanged, using it (since it is uninitialised) gives undefined behaviour.

Incidentally, `scanf("%d %d\n",&t,&k)` can have some unexpected effects due to behaviour of the `\n` on some input.     There are plenty of questions here providing examples of problems, and explanations.   In short:  remove the `\n'.

The first sample has a statement  `count[c-'A']++` and the second replaces it with `count[str[i]-'A']++`.     Apart from the concern with `count` being unitialised, this assumes `c - 'A'` is a valid index.  There are two circumstances it will not be, so the operation will increment a value outside `count`.

- Input other than an uppercase letter causes `c - 'A'` to have a value outside the range `0` to `25`.
- [Obscure, but permitted by the standard, and there are character sets with this characteristic].    The set of uppercase letters is not guaranteed to be contiguous, so `'Z' - 'A'` may be a value other than `25`.

In both cases above, you need to more rigorously check the input for validity.

`int min = 999999` has two potential problems.  With a compiler that only supports a 16-bit `int` type, the initialiser overflows, and may give a value different than you expect.   If the compiler supports a large enough `int` (e.g. 32 bit or better) then your program will not correctly handle input values more than `999999`.   If all input values exceed that value, the calculated value of `min` will be incorrect.